# PHP not passing variable off correctly

Tags: php, mongodb, variables

Hi guys im setting up a new form using mongoDB im passing variables off the form to the update string, What im having for an issue is when i pass off the string like this something goes wrong and nothing is updated

```
$mongo->update(array('_id'=>$ID),array('$set'=>array('fields.Food'=>$FOOD)));
```

but if i hard code the ID in it will update

```
$mongo->update(array('_id'=>1),array('$set'=>array('fields.Food'=>$FOOD)));
```

then the document reflects the new values
but when i just have the post PHP echo $ID it shows it as the correct number in this case

```
echo($ID)
```

outputs

```
1
```

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($ID)`?

Comment: it returns `string(9) "1"`

Comment: Is it required to be an interger?

Comment: yes it is needed to be a int. Also add the `intval($ID)` into my update code or see what it returns?

Comment: Something is wrong with the value, `var_dump()` shows the length of the value is 9.

Comment: thank you @Adelphia that was perfect. if you want to post that as an answer ill give you the credit! also gergo i didn't post the actual numbers

Comment: @RyanLewis Glad to help, posted the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the $ID value was required to be an integer.

use `intval($ID)` to convert it :)